# How to Build a Software Framework

Tags: c#, java, c, web, frameworks

I am thinking of developing a software framework for my dissertation.  I still have to decide what issues the software framework will address.

I have searched over the internet for information about how to build a software framework but I can't seem to find any.  Can anyone direct me to a website or any other resource which explains the basic steps of building a framework please?

For now, the steps of any framework will do.  Thank you.

Edit:

I only found this website up till now:

http://blog.robustsoftware.co.uk/2009/09/bdd-from-scratch-build-your-own.html

Comment: i don't think this is a question. If you don't know what problem your framework should address, how do you even know that it's going to be a framework in the end?

Comment: I just want to know how one goes around building the framework at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [net tuts guide to building a PHP 5 framework](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1/).

It includes:

- Creating authentication handler, database abstraction layer and template manager
- Bringing these objects together
- Using the framework to manage content, and power our site
- Creating a fantastic front end design.
- Designing for the login process by storyboarding
- How the Framework can be extended and expanded

Comment: what makes you sure he wants anything like that if he doesn't even know the problem he wants to solve? His example is a testing framework, which seems quite different from your example. (Not saying that it is not possible that this is exactly what he is looking for).

Comment: "Can anyone direct me to a website or any other resource which explains the basic steps of building a framework please?" That made me sure he wanted a website with steps on building a framework, he didn't mind regarding language/functionality just the concepts.